# PHP class variable loads unproperly

Tags: php, internationalization

```
i18n Object
(
    [localization] => 
    [timezone] => 
    [lang] => 
    [english] => english
    [strings] => Array
        (
            [main/welcome] => welcome
        )

)
```

I get this from

```
class i18n {
    public $localization;
    public $timezone;
    public $lang;
    private static $instance; //The single instance
    public static function getInstance(){
        if (self::$instance == null){
            self::$instance = new self($localization);
        }
        return self::$instance ;
     }
    public function __construct($localization) {
        $this->$localization = $localization;
        // if($this->localization == 'english') { // ill be writing these sick things like idiot for each translation, FML
            $this->strings = english::load();
        //}
        // TODO $this->strings = $localization::load();
    }
    public function getString($string_id) {
        return $this->strings[$string_id];
    }
}
?>
```

I dont get how it happens, can somebody please explain me what happened?
I think it should work different, like having english in the localization for example... I would like to know how it happened, in advance have some way to fix it as I am struggling trought my own CMS or something, I was just bored so I code, but I dont manage how to get this issue done...

It must be something inside php... does php support internalization? Does it have internal system for that? I would like to know, I dont want invent whole wheel again, just part of it. Thank you very much...

I really wonder what it does and thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Then you'll also know if a value is empty or `NULL`. There is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you do not have all error_reporting on. Please make sure to do that, then you should see something like `Notice: Undefined variable: $localization` from your code. If you update your code with the below, you should see  english in the localization.

```
public static function getInstance($localization = 'english'){
    if (self::$instance == null){
        self::$instance = new self($localization);
    }
    return self::$instance ;
 }

public function __construct($localization) {
    $this->localization = $localization;
    // if($this->localization == 'english') { // ill be writing these sick things like idiot for each translation, FML
        $this->strings = english::load();
    //}
    // TODO $this->strings = $localization::load();
}
public function getString($string_id) {
    return $this->strings[$string_id];
}
```

Then instantiate your class as,

```
$object = i18n::getInstance('french'); // for languages other than english
```

So, basically I changed two things

1. I added an argument `$localization` with your getInstance method.
2. I changed the line `$this->$localization = $localization;` to `$this->localization = $localization;` in your constructor.

Please observe there is a difference between `$this->$localization = $localization;` and `$this->localization = $localization;`. $this->$localization is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Meaning once you are passing lets say `english` as an argument to your constructor it makes a variable called $english and assigns value in it. Thats why you are seeing the `english = english` thing

Comment: I am doing it exactly like that... 
>$i18n = i18n::getInstance('english');

Comment: I am not sure whyy I get english= 'english'

Comment: are you sure? you are not passing any arguments with your `getInstance` in the code that you provided. In that case maybe you should update your code so that people get a better idea on your problem?

Comment: @YuriNko please check my update. I have explained why you are seeing the english=english

Comment: Im glad I could help!